# I don't understand why I lost this hand in Texas Hold'em (help please)

Tags: soft-question

I am still new at Poker and I have been learning all the hands, but on this all in scenario I lost when I had two pairs King(hearts) 5(clubs) the other player had King(diamonds) Ace(hearts) the community cards were: 7(hearts) K(spades) 10(hearts) 5(diamonds) 10(clubs). I made two pairs with my 5 and king and i could even use the 2 tens so why the other player won with only one king ? the ace isn't a kicker here as i had a 5 right ? Please see the picture for more details .. and thank you so much for taking the time to answer my query.[image]

Comment: Hi @Rakki and welcome, you lost this hand because of the pair of 10's on the board. In poker, the best 5-card hand wins. Your hand is KKTT7 while your opponent's hand is KKTTA. Your 2-pair of kings and 5's got counterfeited by a larger pair on the board.

Comment: thank you so much Clarko for answering my query , now I do understand now why I lost this hand. Can I just ask another quick question regarding this same hand: what would have happened If there was only one 10 in the board (no a pair) but another card instead. Would have lost against King, ace with my 5 king when I had two pairs or his ace kicker would have beat me again ?

Comment: if, instead of the last 10, the river was a black 2, which does not change the hand for anybody, you would have won because you would have KK55 and a 10 as kicker. your opponent (the original winner) would have just a pair of K and the other opponent (on the left) would still have a pair of 7. so yeah, that last 10 made you lose the hand

Comment: Thank you so much jackhammer , all my doubts have been clear , I really appreciate your help and hopefully I will see you one day on the EPT final table.

Answer (score 0):

A poker hand consists of 5 cards and 5 cards only!

In Texas Hold'em, you can make a hand with any combination of community cards and your hole cards (using 0, 1 or 2 of your hole cards, with the rest coming from the board)

Your best possible 5-card hand is two pair with 7 as a kicker, as in KKTT7 (T stands for "ten") Your opponent has the same two-pair, but his kicker is an ace (KKTTA), so his hand is stronger than yours and he wins the pot.

Your "third pair" is irrelevant here, as you'd need poker hands consisting of six cards to make it count

Comment: Thank you so much David for answering my query I really appreciate it .